# How to bulk-allocate for boost::ptr_vector and call the stored class' constructor?

Tags: c++, optimization, boost

For an evolutionary algorithm, I require a container to store a population of individuals - i.e., a vector of objects. I need to sort that vector at each iteration, which should be efficient. Additionally, I want to avoid cache misses, so I'd like to bulk-allocate the entire population up front (its size is known and fixed). However, I am not content with the class' default constructur, but would like to to call a specific constructor on each object.

I've run `cachegrind` on my current code and found that the highest number of cache misses occurs in `Individual::operator <(const Individual &other)` that is my predicate for sorting the population. Since my population is sorted on every iteration, I figure that optimizing at this point would give me the most benefits. I've interpreted cache misses in `operator <()` to stem from the distribution of `Individual` objects over my system's memory - if it were otherwise, I'd see cache misses in the accessor functions of, e.g., the `std::vector<double>` that stores the individual's parameters, right?

From my requirements, I have selected `boost::ptr_vector`. Mainly because it allows me to (a) keep my objects in one chunk of memory while offering an implementation of `sort()` that does not create and destroy temporary objects.

Now, in order to avoid cache misses, I'd like to allocate the whole population in one piece. What I'd like to do is something along the lines of...

```
boost::ptr_vector<Individual> population;
auto *rawPopulaton = new Individual[populationSize](templateObject);
population.transfer(population.begin(), rawPopulation, populationSize);
return population;
```

I am, however, unsure how to realize this in order to *not* violate the concept of spacial locality (i.e., I want to avoid cache misses). I could happily loop with:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < populationSize; ++i) {
    auto *individual = new Individual(templateObject);
    population.push_back(individual);
}
```

... but I fear that exactly this would lead to my population being distributed over different chunks of memory.

So here are actually two questions:

1. Are my design choices right wrt the optimization goal?
2. How do I bulk-allocate my population *and* call a specific constructor?

Comment: <1> Is there actually a performance bottleneck caused by cache misses? (Any measurements done?)  

<2> How about using a [memory pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/pool/doc/html/) to allocate the objects on? (Or write it yourself, using [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new))

Comment: To be more specific regarding <1> -- misses due to the allocation, rather than say non-sequential access of that memory that seems very likely to happen.

Comment: @DanMašek: Regarding (1), yes, I did measurements. I'll update my question to reflect these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have selected boost::ptr_vector. Mainly because it allows me to (a) keep my objects in one chunk of memory

It doesn't do this. Your `transfer` approach comes close, but

- there's non-locality between the "index" and the backing storage.
- sorting breaks the perfect order

> while offering an implementation of sort() that does not create and destroy temporary objects.

You might be looking for `stable_vector` or intrusive containers.

---

> Are my design choices right wrt the optimization goal?

I'm not sure but I doubt it. (Have you profiled your bottlenecks? You seem to suggest that reordering should physically re-order things for sequential access. In that case, just use `vector<X>` instead of `ptr_vector<X>`?)

> How do I bulk-allocate my population and call a specific constructor?

Have you considered `std::fill[_n]` and `std::generate[_n]`?

Comment: `std::generate` was unknown to me until now - thanks for that hint! But wrt locality *and* efficient sorting, I'm unsure whether there's a data structure that gives me both. `stable_vector` uses non-contiguous chunks of memory, where `std::sort` creates temporary objects. Or perhaps I'm just misunderstanding something. Additionally, I've updated my original question with information from cachegrind; could you have a look at my assumptions, please?

Comment: Your cache misses appear to be due random access. Contiguity doesn't matter a lot when the jumps are "random". Perhaps you should use a heap/treap? Something that's cheaper to keep sorted. IIRC `std::priority_queue` uses similar things internally. See also `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap` and `std::sort_heap`

Comment: Thanks, these are extremely helpful pointers. I'll investigate and tune my code accordingly. Thanks a lot!